# Convert MP3 Bytes array into PCM byte array in Java

Tags: java, audio, mp3, pcm

I have a MP3 stored in byte array. When I write this byte array into the file, I can play that file using vlc Media player.
Now I would like to convert this into PCM byte array in java.

```
public byte [] convertMP3IntoPCM(byte [] mp3Data){
      //Process
      return pcmData;
}
```

Which library am I suppose to use.

Thanks,
Shantanu